# Possible values of HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In ASP.NET Core, with Identity, I always get this:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Identity.Application"
```

What is the significance of this? Are there any other values it could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I setup everything to use Windows authentication, I get `HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType = Kerberos`, that would be an example.

Also, when I do my own login:

```
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
            new List<Claim>{
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                new Claim(PartnersUserDataClaim, userData),
                new Claim(ModuleNameClaim, moduleName)
            },
            "SSO/Windows"));

        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(APIAuthSchemeName, principal);
```

`"SSO/Windows"` ends up being the value of `HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType`

So, I would say this attribute can be set by whatever layer is able of creating your principal, whether it's a provided middleware like the IIS one for Kerberos, or your own layer.

Comment: I'm not using ASP.NET Core 2 Identity, and after third-party (Google) auth via IdentityServer4, the value is literally the stringified name of the struct field `AuthenticationTypes.Federated` rather than the _value_ in the field, which is `Federated`. That seems to come from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/Claims/AuthenticationTypes.cs) although I can't actually find `AuthenticationTypes` anywhere in the Object Browser when my project is open...

Comment: It seems to come from `TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType`, which is hard-coded to that value in [`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/TokenValidationParameters.cs)... which, for some reason, is hidden away in the AzureAD extensions project. Clear as mud...